# Alter GORM database column

Tags: grails, grails-orm, sqlexception

I have a ImageController function that takes input data from a form.gsp file and adds it to a Profile class.  The Profile class has a `byte[] photo` field, and using a MultiPart HTTP Request transferTo() method, the file is replicated in the database if size is < 200KB.

My issue is each time I try to upload, I get a SQLException stating that the input value is too large for a PHOTO_BINARY(255) column.

First, why is a byte[] array mapped to a column limiter?  To move around this, would `byte[] photo= new byte[200*1024]` work?

Second, what is necessary to alter said column to a medium blob of 16777215 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `maxSize` constraint, e.g.

```
static constraints = {
   photo maxSize: 16777215
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type of the column to blob in the mappings.

```
static mapping = {
   photo type: "binary" // or "blob"
}
```

Hope that helps